# Unit tests on methods/publication that requires authentication in meteor

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

I'm writing unit test for my `Meteor 1.4.2` application, where few of my methods requires authentication before processing.
How should I test these methods?

So far, I've written a test with `practicalmeteor:mocha` to create a new user and login with that user.

```
describe('login method', function () {
let logingKey;
beforeEach(function () {
  Meteor.users.remove({});
  const createUser = Meteor.server.method_handlers['registerUser'];
  let params = {
    username: 'testUsername'
  }
  res = createUser.apply({}, [params]);
  logingKey = res.key;
});

it('can provide authentication', function () {
  const loginUser = Meteor.server.method_handlers['login'];
  let params = {
    key: logingKey
  }
  console.log(params);
  loginUser.apply({}, [params]);
});
```

I've written a custom login handler to login with the generated key which works fine with application, but in test results I'm getting following error.

```
Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at AccountsServer.Ap._setLoginToken (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:889:35)
at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:288:10
at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (packages/meteor.js:671:12)
at AccountsServer.Ap._loginUser (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:287:10)
at AccountsServer.Ap._attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:349:12)
at Object.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:533:21)
at Object.methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks_kadira.js:2731:30)
at Test.<anonymous> (imports/api/methods/loginUser.tests.js:30:17)
at run (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha-core/server.js:34:29)
at Context.wrappedFunction (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha-core/server.js:63:33)
```

What could be wrong here? any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

[Original post on meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-login-method-test/32597)

**UPDATE**

Ok! here is my confustion, Let say I've a write a unit test for this method, How should I verify or get the userId here.

```
Meteor.methods({
  userStatus:function(update){
      check(update, {online: String})
      if (! this.userId) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('error-not-authorized','User need to login', {method: "userStatus"})
      }
      try {
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$set: {'status.online': !!parseInt(update.online)}})
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error",e);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly invoking a method handler without an appropriate context (which should be a [Method Invocation object](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods), while you provide an empty object). The `login` method handler attempts to get the connection id and fails to do so.

If you want to test the integration of your package with the `accounts-base` package (and basically you do, as you are calling some of its code), you can create a connection and call the method with that connection.

```js
let connection = DDP.connect(Meteor.absoluteUrl());
// prepare the login data
const params = {/*...*/};
connection.call('login', params);
// test post conditions
connection.disconnect();
```

---

**Edit** (following question edit):

The answer remains pretty much the same. Once you have called the `login` method and logged in the user, the connection state on the server should include the logged-in user's id. Now you can call the methods that require the user to be logged in.

Note that you should probably use `this.userId` on all occasions (and not `Meteor.userId()`).

Comment: you mean, I can't run a unit test on methods that requires logged in user.

Comment: I mean, you cannot call a method handler that relies on an invocation object without the invocation object. Either mock one up (including a connection) or use a temporary connection as demonstrated.

Comment: I've update question, how should I write a unit test in this case, that' my problem is

Comment: I updated the answer. On a side note, try to provide the actual details of your issue in the first place, as those are almost 2 separate questions (and this site is aimed at helping specific issues, so users with a question regarding method calls in tests could have used the "first" answer, and users with a question regarding testing when a logged-in user is required could use the "second" answer, which would likely be better as 2 distinct questions).

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I was confused with the approaches, so Initially I tried to log in and after that I tried to call the same in other method tests.
I'll keep this in mind to make separate questions.

Comment: So to be clear, I should connect to dpp. and login in `beforeEach` block of tests, and then call my method, then disconnects dpp connection `afterEach` block.

Comment: That is one way of achieving this. It is worthwhile if you need the same initial state for a group of tests.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131707/discussion-between-ankibalyan-and-masteram).